# regex matching long string broke with \ read from file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

In file I read I have lines:

fileContent.py

```
header.Description      ="long"\
"description"
header.Priority         =1
header.Type             ="short"
```

I need regex, that would match with lines that are broken and with ones that aren't. Now I'm doing it in such way:

```
with open('fileContent.py') as f:
    fileContent = f.read()
template = r'\nheader\.%s\s*=\s*.+(\\n.+)?'
values = ['Description', 'Priority']
for value in values:
    print re.search(re.compile(template % str(value)), fileContent).group(0)
```

and I receive:

```
header.Priority         ="1"

header.Description      ="long"\
```

If I change my `template` to not use raw string:

```
template = '\nheader\\.%s\\s*=\\s*.+(\\\n.+)?'
```

I receive:

```
header.Priority         ="1"
header.Type             ="short"

header.Description      ="long"\
"description"
```

How can I build regex that would match something like 2 line broken string as above and also only one line string? I don't want to have line containing `header.Type`, because I'm not looking for it!
Why `'\\\n'` doesn't work as I expected - matching backslash+newline sequence.

Comment: Parsing python (or any other formal language) with regexes is doomed to fail. Try a dedicated parser (in case of python, the `ast` module).

Comment: Matching backslash+newline is done with `re.search('\\\\\\n',s)`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @Evpok Sad to say, but not. I have the same result as with `r'\nheader\.%s\s*=\s*.+(\\n.+)?'`, so I receive "long"\ .
@georg could you tell me something more? I think that's great idea and that's exactly what I need. I have file that begins with header attributes assigning, so could you give me shortcut to iterate on that attributes to find e.g. header.Priority and value assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your pattern is not matching `backslash+newline` is that you have `r'\\n'` which means `a backslash + 'n'`.

For the case above, you could try this regex:

```
\nheader\.Description\s*=\s*[^\r\n]+(?P<broken_line>\\\n.+)
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qM9gR6/1).

**BUT** it is **not advisable** to parse code with regular expressions because Python code is not a regular language. Use [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html).

Comment: That perfectly matches line with Description, but not with Priority. And if I put * at the end it matches Priority line, but not description.
However, as you suggest there is probably better way, to deal with what I want in other way, I'll use AST.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
(?:[^\r\n]+\\[\r\n]*)+|[^\r\n]+
```

[See the DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kI0oQ0/1)

Comment: That perfectly finds lines, even that broken, thanks! But that seems not working for me as I wanted, because if I try to find line with header (e.g. with this: `r'(header.*)+(?:[^\r\n]+\\[\r\n]*)+|[^\r\n]+'` that doesn't find me line header.Description      ="long description", I don't understand why.